# JavaScript alert if selection reaches number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

I want to display an alert if the user selects more than 2 items.
https://jsfiddle.net/338jL5qm/

jQuery:

```
var sb = $('.selected').length;
$('#row td.u').bind('click', function () {
    if (sb == 2) {
        alert("working");
        return;
    };
    $(this).html($(this).html() == '1' ? '2' : '1');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected u');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='row'>
    <table id='tbl'>
        <tr>
            <td class='u' id='_1a'>1</td>
            <td class='u' id='_1b'>1</td>
            <td class='u' id='_1c'>1</td>
            <td class='u' id='_1d'>1</td>
            <td class='u' id='_1e'>1</td>
            <td class='u' id='_1f'>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
.selected{
    border: thin black solid;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to call `var sb = $('.selected').length;` inside click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `sb` is setting on page load and never been changed. Put `var sb = $('.selected').length` in click event to change it on every click.

```
$('#row td.u').bind('click', function () {
    var sb = $('.selected').length;
    if (sb == 2) {
        alert("working");
        return;
    };
    $(this).html($(this).html() == '1' ? '2' : '1');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected u');
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/338jL5qm/2/)